# Numpy: getting incorrect shape information

Tags: python, numpy, shapes

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt

train = genfromtxt('/Users/hhimanshu/Downloads/dataset/digitrecognizer/a.csv', delimiter=',', names=True)
```

When I run shape information, I get

```
# if train is ndarray
print 'shape(Tuple of array dimensions) = ', train.shape
print 'dimension(Number of array dimensions) = ', train.ndim
print 'size(Number of elements in array) = ', train.size
# print 'data type = ', train.dtype
train['label']
train['pixel783']
```

I get

```
shape(Tuple of array dimensions) =  (9,)
dimension(Number of array dimensions) =  1
size(Number of elements in array) =  9
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

The data looks like

```
label,pixel0,pixel1,pixel2,pixel3,pixel4,pixel5,pixel6,pixel7,pixel8,pixel9,pixel10,pixel11,pixel12,pixel13,pixel14,pixel15,pixel16,pixel17,pixel18,pixel19,pixel20,pixel21,pixel22,pixel23,pixel24,pixel25,pixel26,pixel27,pixel28,pixel29,pixel30,pixel31,pixel32,pixel33,pixel34,pixel35,pixel36,pixel37,pixel38,pixel39,pixel40,pixel41,pixel42,pixel43,pixel44,pixel45,pixel46,pixel47,pixel48,pixel49,pixel50,pixel51,pixel52,pixel53,pixel54,pixel55,pixel56,pixel57,pixel58,pixel59,pixel60,pixel61,pixel62,pixel63,pixel64,pixel65,pixel66,pixel67,pixel68,pixel69,pixel70,pixel71,pixel72,pixel73,pixel74,pixel75,pixel76,pixel77,pixel78,pixel79,pixel80,pixel81,pixel82,pixel83,pixel84,pixel85,pixel86,pixel87,pixel88,pixel89,pixel90,pixel91,pixel92,pixel93,pixel94,pixel95,pixel96,pixel97,pixel98,pixel99,pixel100,pixel101,pixel102,pixel103,pixel104,pixel105,pixel106,pixel107,pixel108,pixel109,pixel110,pixel111,pixel112,pixel113,pixel114,pixel115,pixel116,pixel117,pixel118,pixel119,pixel120,pixel121,pixel122,pixel123,pixel124,pixel125,pixel126,pixel127,pixel128,pixel129,pixel130,pixel131,pixel132,pixel133,pixel134,pixel135,pixel136,pixel137,pixel138,pixel139,pixel140,pixel141,pixel142,pixel143,pixel144,pixel145,pixel146,pixel147,pixel148,pixel149,pixel150,pixel151,pixel152,pixel153,pixel154,pixel155,pixel156,pixel157,pixel158,pixel159,pixel160,pixel161,pixel162,pixel163,pixel164,pixel165,pixel166,pixel167,pixel168,pixel169,pixel170,pixel171,pixel172,pixel173,pixel174,pixel175,pixel176,pixel177,pixel178,pixel179,pixel180,pixel181,pixel182,pixel183,pixel184,pixel185,pixel186,pixel187,pixel188,pixel189,pixel190,pixel191,pixel192,pixel193,pixel194,pixel195,pixel196,pixel197,pixel198,pixel199,pixel200,pixel201,pixel202,pixel203,pixel204,pixel205,pixel206,pixel207,pixel208,pixel209,pixel210,pixel211,pixel212,pixel213,pixel214,pixel215,pixel216,pixel217,pixel218,pixel219,pixel220,pixel221,pixel222,pixel223,pixel224,pixel225,pixel226,pixel227,pixel228,pixel229,pixel230,pixel231,pixel232,pixel233,pixel234,pixel235,pixel236,pixel237,pixel238,pixel239,pixel240,pixel241,pixel242,pixel243,pixel244,pixel245,pixel246,pixel247,pixel248,pixel249,pixel250,pixel251,pixel252,pixel253,pixel254,pixel255,pixel256,pixel257,pixel258,pixel259,pixel260,pixel261,pixel262,pixel263,pixel264,pixel265,pixel266,pixel267,pixel268,pixel269,pixel270,pixel271,pixel272,pixel273,pixel274,pixel275,pixel276,pixel277,pixel278,pixel279,pixel280,pixel281,pixel282,pixel283,pixel284,pixel285,pixel286,pixel287,pixel288,pixel289,pixel290,pixel291,pixel292,pixel293,pixel294,pixel295,pixel296,pixel297,pixel298,pixel299,pixel300,pixel301,pixel302,pixel303,pixel304,pixel305,pixel306,pixel307,pixel308,pixel309,pixel310,pixel311,pixel312,pixel313,pixel314,pixel315,pixel316,pixel317,pixel318,pixel319,pixel320,pixel321,pixel322,pixel323,pixel324,pixel325,pixel326,pixel327,pixel328,pixel329,pixel330,pixel331,pixel332,pixel333,pixel334,pixel335,pixel336,pixel337,pixel338,pixel339,pixel340,pixel341,pixel342,pixel343,pixel344,pixel345,pixel346,pixel347,pixel348,pixel349,pixel350,pixel351,pixel352,pixel353,pixel354,pixel355,pixel356,pixel357,pixel358,pixel359,pixel360,pixel361,pixel362,pixel363,pixel364,pixel365,pixel366,pixel367,pixel368,pixel369,pixel370,pixel371,pixel372,pixel373,pixel374,pixel375,pixel376,pixel377,pixel378,pixel379,pixel380,pixel381,pixel382,pixel383,pixel384,pixel385,pixel386,pixel387,pixel388,pixel389,pixel390,pixel391,pixel392,pixel393,pixel394,pixel395,pixel396,pixel397,pixel398,pixel399,pixel400,pixel401,pixel402,pixel403,pixel404,pixel405,pixel406,pixel407,pixel408,pixel409,pixel410,pixel411,pixel412,pixel413,pixel414,pixel415,pixel416,pixel417,pixel418,pixel419,pixel420,pixel421,pixel422,pixel423,pixel424,pixel425,pixel426,pixel427,pixel428,pixel429,pixel430,pixel431,pixel432,pixel433,pixel434,pixel435,pixel436,pixel437,pixel438,pixel439,pixel440,pixel441,pixel442,pixel443,pixel444,pixel445,pixel446,pixel447,pixel448,pixel449,pixel450,pixel451,pixel452,pixel453,pixel454,pixel455,pixel456,pixel457,pixel458,pixel459,pixel460,pixel461,pixel462,pixel463,pixel464,pixel465,pixel466,pixel467,pixel468,pixel469,pixel470,pixel471,pixel472,pixel473,pixel474,pixel475,pixel476,pixel477,pixel478,pixel479,pixel480,pixel481,pixel482,pixel483,pixel484,pixel485,pixel486,pixel487,pixel488,pixel489,pixel490,pixel491,pixel492,pixel493,pixel494,pixel495,pixel496,pixel497,pixel498,pixel499,pixel500,pixel501,pixel502,pixel503,pixel504,pixel505,pixel506,pixel507,pixel508,pixel509,pixel510,pixel511,pixel512,pixel513,pixel514,pixel515,pixel516,pixel517,pixel518,pixel519,pixel520,pixel521,pixel522,pixel523,pixel524,pixel525,pixel526,pixel527,pixel528,pixel529,pixel530,pixel531,pixel532,pixel533,pixel534,pixel535,pixel536,pixel537,pixel538,pixel539,pixel540,pixel541,pixel542,pixel543,pixel544,pixel545,pixel546,pixel547,pixel548,pixel549,pixel550,pixel551,pixel552,pixel553,pixel554,pixel555,pixel556,pixel557,pixel558,pixel559,pixel560,pixel561,pixel562,pixel563,pixel564,pixel565,pixel566,pixel567,pixel568,pixel569,pixel570,pixel571,pixel572,pixel573,pixel574,pixel575,pixel576,pixel577,pixel578,pixel579,pixel580,pixel581,pixel582,pixel583,pixel584,pixel585,pixel586,pixel587,pixel588,pixel589,pixel590,pixel591,pixel592,pixel593,pixel594,pixel595,pixel596,pixel597,pixel598,pixel599,pixel600,pixel601,pixel602,pixel603,pixel604,pixel605,pixel606,pixel607,pixel608,pixel609,pixel610,pixel611,pixel612,pixel613,pixel614,pixel615,pixel616,pixel617,pixel618,pixel619,pixel620,pixel621,pixel622,pixel623,pixel624,pixel625,pixel626,pixel627,pixel628,pixel629,pixel630,pixel631,pixel632,pixel633,pixel634,pixel635,pixel636,pixel637,pixel638,pixel639,pixel640,pixel641,pixel642,pixel643,pixel644,pixel645,pixel646,pixel647,pixel648,pixel649,pixel650,pixel651,pixel652,pixel653,pixel654,pixel655,pixel656,pixel657,pixel658,pixel659,pixel660,pixel661,pixel662,pixel663,pixel664,pixel665,pixel666,pixel667,pixel668,pixel669,pixel670,pixel671,pixel672,pixel673,pixel674,pixel675,pixel676,pixel677,pixel678,pixel679,pixel680,pixel681,pixel682,pixel683,pixel684,pixel685,pixel686,pixel687,pixel688,pixel689,pixel690,pixel691,pixel692,pixel693,pixel694,pixel695,pixel696,pixel697,pixel698,pixel699,pixel700,pixel701,pixel702,pixel703,pixel704,pixel705,pixel706,pixel707,pixel708,pixel709,pixel710,pixel711,pixel712,pixel713,pixel714,pixel715,pixel716,pixel717,pixel718,pixel719,pixel720,pixel721,pixel722,pixel723,pixel724,pixel725,pixel726,pixel727,pixel728,pixel729,pixel730,pixel731,pixel732,pixel733,pixel734,pixel735,pixel736,pixel737,pixel738,pixel739,pixel740,pixel741,pixel742,pixel743,pixel744,pixel745,pixel746,pixel747,pixel748,pixel749,pixel750,pixel751,pixel752,pixel753,pixel754,pixel755,pixel756,pixel757,pixel758,pixel759,pixel760,pixel761,pixel762,pixel763,pixel764,pixel765,pixel766,pixel767,pixel768,pixel769,pixel770,pixel771,pixel772,pixel773,pixel774,pixel775,pixel776,pixel777,pixel778,pixel779,pixel780,pixel781,pixel782,pixel783
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,188,255,94,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,191,250,253,93,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,123,248,253,167,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,80,247,253,208,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,29,207,253,235,77,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,54,209,253,253,88,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,93,254,253,238,170,17,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,210,254,253,159,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,209,253,254,240,81,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,27,253,253,254,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,206,254,254,198,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,168,253,253,196,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,203,253,248,76,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22,188,253,245,93,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,103,253,253,191,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,89,240,253,195,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,220,253,253,80,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,94,253,253,253,94,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,89,251,253,250,131,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,214,218,95,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I believe the shape should be `(9, 784)`, isn't it? What is that I am not doing right here?

**UPDATE**
But when I do the following instead (removing `names=True`)

```
train = genfromtxt(fname='/Users/hhimanshu/Downloads/dataset/digitrecognizer/a.csv', delimiter=',')
```

and run shape information

```
# if train is ndarray
print 'shape(Tuple of array dimensions) = ', train.shape
print 'dimension(Number of array dimensions) = ', train.ndim
print 'size(Number of elements in array) = ', train.size
# print 'data type = ', train.dtype
train['label']
```

I get right dimensions, but label information is lost

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-136-53c55437f109> in <module>()
      4 print 'size(Number of elements in array) = ', train.size
      5 # print 'data type = ', train.dtype
----> 6 train['label']
      7 # train['pixel1']

ValueError: field named label not found.

shape(Tuple of array dimensions) =  (10, 785)
dimension(Number of array dimensions) =  2
size(Number of elements in array) =  7850
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a special case when you use `names = True` : genfromtxt returns astructured array (as pointed by  @'Pierre GM' )  containing the datas in a row.

I would avise you to load separately the header and the datas (with skiprows for example).

Comment: Technically, the output of `genfromtxt` when `names=True` is **not** an array of tuples but a structured array. Each element is actually a special object `np.void`.

Comment: that's what I thought, but I wasn' really sure since it is written in the doc : where did you find the information ?

Answer (score 1):

In numpy, all the elements of a `ndarray` must have the same type. This type can be simple (like `float` or `int`) or more complex, as the combination of several subtypes (like `[('name', '|S16'),('value',float)]`. In that case, we talk of a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), that is, a `ndarray` with a sturctured dtype. Note that you can define a structured dtype where all the subelements have the same type, like `[('first',float),('second',float)]`. Usually, a single element of a structured array is called a record and each of the subelements is called a field.

Consider for example the array:

```
example = np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)], dtype=[('A',int),('B',int),('C',int)])
```

`example` is a structured array consisting of two elements (`(1,2,3)` and `(4,5,6)`), each element (or 'record') having 3 fields. Because it has only 2 elements, its shape is `(2,)`. You can get the number of fields with `len(example.dtype.names)`. The size of this array is 2, because we only have two elements.

Because it's a structured array, we can access each field individually:

```
>>> example['A']
array([1, 4])
```

Anyhow:

---

As stated in the [documentation of `np.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), when you use the `names` parameter, you specifically ask `np.genfromtxt` to return a structured array.

Each element of your output corresponds to a valid row of your file and has as many subelements ('fields') as columns in your file (784). Here, as you had 9 valid rows, the shape of your output is `(9,)`.

Because you didn't give a dtype, `genfromtxt` assumes that each field is a `float`, so the dtype of the output is given by:

```
np.dtype([(name, float) for name in list_of_names])
```

where your `list_of_names` was read from the first valid row of your file.

If now you don't use `names=True`, you actually tell `np.genfromtxt` to read your file as a 2D array of floats, hence the `(9,784)` shape. But because in that case, the output is no longer a structured array, you can't access each column by its name (because it doesn't have any).

Note that in this particular case (all the fields are float), you can switch from the structured to the unstructured view with

```
train.reshape((-1,1)).view(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it, reading the header and then the rest, as suggested by georgesl. I streamlined it by passing everything through a file handle:

```
fh=open(myfile,'r')
header=fh.readline().rstrip("\n").split(",")
data=np.genfromtxt(fh,delimiter=",")
fh.close()
```